# VS2017 C# Creating a New Build Configuration Breaks using statements

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

In VS2017 I'm trying to set up a new configuration for QA. I'm creating the configuration as "QA" and copying settings from "Release". I do have the "Create new project configurations" checkbox checked.

When I switch to the QA build in the dropdown, I'm suddenly greeted with Entity Framework errors that I do not have in Debug or Release.

"The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

And

"The type or namespace name 'EntityConnectionStringBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

If I switch to either Debug or Release, these errors go away and everything is fine and works as expected.

Here's the code that the problem is happening with:

```
using Redacted.Stuff;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MoreRedacted.Stuff
{
public class RedactedClass
{
    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        var self = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name;

        string constr = string.Empty;

#if (DEBUG)
        constr = "connection_dev";
#elif (QA)
        constr = "connection_qa";
#else
        constr = "connection_prod";
#endif

        return new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient",
            ProviderConnectionString = (new ConfigManager()).ConnectionStrings["RedactedConnection"].ConnectionString,
            Metadata = $"res://{ self }/EF.EFRedacted.csdl|res://{ self }/EF.EFRedacted.ssdl|res://{ self }/EF.EFRedacted.msl"
        }.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Never seen that before. I'd close VS, nuke all the bin and obj directories by hand, reload, and do a full build.  If it still was giving those errors, I'd put it in qa then remove and replace the nuget packages for EF, clean and build.

Comment: In the project file, are there any conditions declared on the elements that reference the assemblies that contain the respective Entity Framework types?

Comment: There are conditions being checked in the method where it's doing this, but it shouldn't have a direct impact. I'll edit the question to add the code.

Comment: Huh, after deleting the obj and bin folders I'm getting the error on all 3 configurations...the plot thickens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out...it seems that even though this project is a copy of another project (I'm splitting it apart to be MEF plug-in based) it didn't bring over the packages. I checked and even though the original project had EntityFramework installed...actually that does make sense because the original project didn't have a QA configuration.

So I guess the important take away is that nuget packages break if a project is copied and then a new configuration is added to the mix. (I'm assuming it's because of how nuget sets up the packages in the projects).